# Подключение к Wi-Fi с помощью cmd/Windows Script Host

Tags: windows, cmd, bat, wifi, wsh

Как подключиться к новой сети Wi-Fi через cmd/Windows Script Host?
Можно ли как-то подключиться к сети Wi-Fi, к которой компьютер ещё не подключался?
Из доступных мне средств: cmd и JScript.
Powershell использовать не могу, т.к скрипт должен работать на Windows 7, а Powershell там сильно урезан.
SSID и пароль сети вводит пользователь, никаких других данных он вводить не должен.

Comment: Кто мешает поставить `WPF 5.1` на windows 7?

Comment: Если средствами Windows Batch, то можно схитрив, экспортировать нужный профиль со всеми нужными настройками: **netsh wlan export  profile name...**. А затем на целевой машине сформировать по образцу необходимый XML-файл профиля, затем добавить его, соответственно:    **netsh wlan add profile filename=...**